# Printer problems with Samsung C410W after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: printing, samsung, 19.04

My Samsung C410W printer worked perfectly with 18.10 (Ubuntu and Xubuntu) but now fails after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04.

I have seen multiple different error messages when I try to print, including

SPL-C ERROR - FALSE

SPL-C ERROR - uw_color < 5

SPL-C ERROR - Insufficient Memory

My SPL-C version is 5.59 05-04-2012

The printer works perfectly from Windows 10 and if I boot to an older version of Ubuntu (e.g. 18.10)

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the Samsung drivers uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz and uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Open Printer Properties on the old system and carefully note `Device URI` and `Make and Model` (these are my translations, could be slightly different). Copy them to the new system. Does that help?

Comment: I compared Device URI and Make and Model on new and old systems: Old URI:
dnssd://Samsung%20C410%20Series%20(SEC001599ECF95E)._printer._tcp.local/ (Samsung C410 Series)
New URI: socket://192.168.0.220
Samsung C410 Series. Both work in 18.10 (Xubuntu) and neither in 19.04 (Ubuntu)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, for now I'm using virtual box with ubuntu 18.04 just to print (or ask my girlfriend, she has Windows 10)